# How to track USER_ID generated by Google analytics which came from certain campaign/utm?

Tags: google-analytics, utm

when somebody register on my website, Google Analytics genrate a new USER ID form him. How can I label/track generated USER_IDs which came from certain campaign (i.e. form certain custom URL with utm parameters)?

Thx for help.

Answer (score 0):

In the first step you should push the UID (or CID) as a Dimension into your GA Account. So you are able to export the UID/CID through the API (or CSV). Here is a article how to do this: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/tag-manager/lcTvzfvcTvU;context-place=topicsearchin/tag-manager/category$3Aadvanced-setup--implementation%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false

If you have the ID as a Dimension you can build a Segment containing your Campaign. In your reports you now see the IDs.

Another solution would be to fire the dimension with the IDs just if a User is on a page containing the specific parameters.